# powershell restart remote computer ip address with port

Tags: powershell, restart, remote-desktop, rdp

i am trying to restart a server with an ip but it fails with the messege:
Restart-Computer :

```
Failed to restart the computer *.*.*.* with the following error message: The RPC server is unavailable.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restart-Computer -ComputerName *.*.*.* -Credential $Creds -Fo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (*.*.*.*:String) [Restart-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RestartcomputerFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartComputerCommand
```

i have changed that computer's RDP port, how do i specify the port in this command? i can't find it in the documentations or the examples over the internet.
any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Please clarify, you are trying to restart-computer from the host within the same ip subnet?

Comment: no, the server has static ip, and i changed the RDP port to something else, so i use `*.*.*.*:port` address scheme in the connection and it works, but not for the Restart-Computer command.